# Angular $resource: update self from get

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Is there any built-in method or conventionally correct approach to this? I'm not asking about *issuing* an update, but rather, requesting one. I could query for it again, but the goal is that the object reference stay the same.

The approach I've taken so far is to define an instance method called "refresh" that gets the same resource instance by ID and then iterates over its properties, copying them over to the original object (how I love thee `_.extend`). But it seems like something that might already be included functionality in ngResource and I just can't find it. If not, does Angular provide a means to make such a "refresh" method default to all $resources the same way save, delete, etc already are?

---

*So I actually found the answer as I was writing the question, but I'm going to post it and answer anyway in case it might help someone else.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing that and looking stuff up, I realized that `get` is not restricted to being a static method of the resource. What threw me here was that on an instance, it's named `$get`. And lo, `$get` does exactly what I wanted. However it does not seem to be documented on Angular's site -- in fact the site says that only non-GET actions are instance methods, so who'd have thought? I mean, aside from that it seems totally obvious now.